# CiviEvent Confirmation Email not sent due to URL link in text

Tags: civievent

we had a system (CIVICRM 5.10.4, Wordpress 5.0.6) that was sending out confirmation email fine for events until one event where a URL is included in the confirmation email text.  This would cause the confirmation email to be sent quite erratic, often sending only first time, and then not sending out at all for subsequent times until the URL is taken out and it would immediately send out ok.  I believe this would be a bug?

Comment: Just to further update on this phenomenon, after a few hours, i see that the missing  emails with the URL do turn up in my inbox.  and upon looking closing, it seems that it might be those confirmation emails that i have included email address to be CC to.  Are there know issues with the CC emails in the Confirmation Email section ?  Thanks.